# How to write a function that takes in a semantic version number input that is a String

Tags: javascript

HI sorry am a beginner here would want to ask how to return an object that has a key that describes the version?

```js
myFunction(“15.0.9”)
 returns { “major”: 15, “minor”: 0, “patch”: 9 }

myFunctuion(“12.2.4”) 
 returns { “major”: 12, “minor”: 2, “patch”: 4 }
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Can you please tell what have you tried to achieve your goal? What is your expected output?

Comment: @AliValizadeh would want the function returns an object that has a key that describes the version and a corresponding value that represents the actual version value

Answer (score 3):

You can just [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string into it's components, [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) all the components to numbers using the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator, and return an object:

```js
const semver = (s) => {
  const [major, minor, patch] = s.split('.').map(v => +v);
  return { major, minor, patch };
}

console.log(semver("15.0.9"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var GimmeVer = function(vNo){
    var arr = vNo.split('.');
    var res = {
    "major":0,
    "minor":0,
    "patch":0
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if (i == 0)
         res.major=arr[i];
      if (i == 1)
        res.minor = arr[i];
    if (i == 2)
       res.patch = arr[i];
    
    return res;   
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try This

```
function myFunction(data){
    const keys =  ['major', 'minor', 'patch'];
    return data.split('.').reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
        if(keys[i]) acc[keys[i]] = Number(cur);
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```